# Search result heading in Google Custom Search

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-custom-search

I have the following HTML which is indexed by Google Custom Search. I am using Microdata with Schema.org.

```html
<p>
   <link itemprop="url" href="/static/Books/A_Good_Foundation.pdf">
   <a href="/static/Books/A_Good_Foundation.pdf" onclick="trackOutboundLink(‘A Good Foundation’);">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> Read
    </button>
   </a>                             
</p>
```

I want to be able to get `itemprop` on the URL not the HTML page which hosts the URL. I can't modify the PDF.

Any ideas?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you mean. Do you want to include Microdata in the PDF file (instead of the HTML file)?

Answer (score 0):

You're already declaring the .pdf URL to be the URL of the book, although your code doesn't show the `itemtype` to which your `itemprop` belongs.  The `<link>` isn't necessary unless it's required for other purposes:  the `url` property can just as readily be attached to the URL.

```
<p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
   <a itemprop="url" href="/static/Books/A_Good_Foundation.pdf" onclick="trackOutboundLink(‘A Good Foundation’);">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> Read
    </button>
   </a>                             
</p>
```

sdsf